# In python, is there a way to enter a try/except block if a condition is met, otherwise execute the code in the try block plainly?

Tags: python

I would like to execute a loop that attempts to run a block of code, and skips past any iterations that happen to fail. However I would also like to be able to pass in a debug flag, so that if one of the iterations fails the program crashes and the user can see the backtrace to help themselves see where it failed. Essentially, I want to do this:

```
debug = False  # or True
for i in range(10):
    if not debug:
        try:
            # many lines of code
        except:
            print(f'Case {i} failed')
    else:
        # many lines of code
```

However, I don't want to duplicate the `#many lines of code`. I could wrap them in a helper function and do precisely the structure I wrote above, but I'm going to have to pass around a bunch of variables that will add some complexity (aka unit tests that I don't want to write). Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'd just wrap `#many lines of code` in a function. (Is it guaranteed that `debug` can't be modified within that code?) Also, try showing us what `# many lines of code` looks like, perhaps we can optimize them down to one or two lines or define a helper subfunction.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are looking for - if you always want to skip iterations where it fails, then the code should always be in the `try` block. If the debug flag is just for whether it prints or not, the `if` should be in the `except` block.

Comment: If you mean you want the #many lines of code to only run once what you can do is

Comment: ```debug``` will be a flag passed in by the user, my intent is that if there is an error in the ```#many lines of code```, the program will crash without continuing through the loop, and dump the backtrace to the screen. The ```#many lines of code``` includes a function that the user also passes in as a variable, so this is to help them if there is an error in the code they've written and passed to me.

Comment: This pattern shows up several times, so I'd rather not make that many helper functions, but it may just be the simplest was to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best solution shy of factoring out `many lines of code` to its own function (which is often a good idea, but not always) would be to unconditionally use the `try`/`except`, but have the `except` conditionally re-raise the exception:

```
debug = False  # or True
for i in range(10):
    try:
        # many lines of code
    except:
        if debug:
            raise  # Bare raise reraises the exception as if it was never caught
        print(f'Case {i} failed')
```

A caught exception reraised with a bare `raise` leaves no user-visible traces to distinguish it from an uncaught exception; the traceback is unchanged, with no indication of it passing through the `except` block, so the net effect is identical to your original code, aside from `debug` being evaluated later (not at all if no exception occurs) and `many lines of code` appearing only once.

Side-note: Bare `except` blocks are a bad idea. If nothing else, limit it to `except Exception:` so you're not catching and suppressing stuff like `KeyboardInterrupt` or `SystemExit` when not in debug mode.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried that structure, and it works well. And point well taken about ```except Exception:```, that's not something that was in my bag of tricks.

Comment: @Scott: Yar. To be clear, `except Exception:` is still excessively broad. When at all possible, you should explicitly name the targeted exceptions you know how to handle, possibly with multiple `except` blocks (if the handling differs by exception type). But anything is better than bare except blocks (or the explicit equivalent of a bare except, `except BaseException:`). The only time I use broad `except` blocks (even `except Exception:`) is when the response is something uniform to all errors (e.g. rollback a DB transaction, log error message), and it's almost always followed by a reraise.

Comment: Yeah, I try to do so. It's not possible in this case, since in those many lines of code I execute a function that the user passes in, and I want to catch any (unknown) errors in their code.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use a function, just one line more does not matter too much.

Otherwise, if there is no need to test `debug`, There is no need to repeat the `else` block. Because if statements in `try` don't raise error, then the it will execute and result will be shown normally.